# verify which part of dataframe string cannot convert to string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
from datetime import datetime

df1=pd.DataFrame({'date':['2016-02-02','2013','2015-02-03','2014-03-02']})
try:
    pd.to_datetime(df1)
except ValueError:
  print("second is wrong")
```

we see that second value is not valid data format for datetime %Y-%m-%d
so what should I wrote to create desired output like this with pandas method

```
true
false 
true 
true
```

**rather than** using

```
try:
    res = bool(datetime.strptime(test_str, format))
except ValueError:
    res = False
```

to testing the whole dataframe with a for loop?

EDIT: this is just a testing dataframe, the real dataframe is way larger than this one, the reason I want to avoid for loop trying to make it run faster (as we know apply+lambda run faster than for loop). It would be better if using pandas local method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try and except is actually good practice. You can wrap it into a function which you can apply:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


def datetime_if_possible(dt):
    try:
        return datetime.fromisoformat(dt)
    except ValueError:
        return None  # or any other default value


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2016-02-02','2013','2015-02-03','2014-03-02']})

df1['parsed'] = df1['date'].apply(datetime_if_possible)
```

---

```
         date     parsed
0  2016-02-02 2016-02-02
1        2013        NaT
2  2015-02-03 2015-02-03
3  2014-03-02 2014-03-02
```

Comment: this is a sample dataframe of a big dataframe though. The whole point of replacing "for" here is to find a faster way running it.

Comment: Did you actually measure the time it runs? I somewhat doubt that this would be your bottleneck.

Comment: it take one minute though

Comment: can you compare it to `to_datetime` (with valid dates only) This would give you some kind of upper limit what you could get from optimisation

Answer (score 1):

pandas *"apply()"* function is one of the simplistic way to avoid for loop, with specifying predefined format. This answer is an extension to the one provided by @Raphael, with the flexibility to format and print the required boolean values.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def check_date(date):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
        print(True)
    except ValueError:
        print(False)

df1=pd.DataFrame({'date':['2016-02-02','2013','2015-02-03','2014-03-02']})
df1["date"].apply(check_date)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `str.match` or match the `%Y-%m-%d` pattern and `pd.to_datetime` to filter the invalid date.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2016-02-02','2013','2015-02-03','2014-03-02','2014-03-32']})

m = df1['date'].str.match('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}') & pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors="coerce").notna()
```

```
print(df1['date'].str.match('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'))

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

```
print(pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors="coerce"))

0   2016-02-02
1   2013-01-01
2   2015-02-03
3   2014-03-02
4          NaT
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

```
print(m)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

Comment: simply match the format? that's brutal, but how do you check whether month is valid or not? like month 99 is not appropriate?

Comment: @XJTLUmedia Then use another robust regex.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Dates cannot be completely covered by regex. Think of the 29th Feb which.

Comment: @Raphael At least there is no such data in OP's example data.